# Apexcharts - How to change the y-axis step size value and tooltip not showing string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, apexcharts

I am using [apexcharts.js](https://apexcharts.com). I am using the below code on my page. I have two issues

1. How to change the y-axis step size value? As of now, it's talking 20.

[image]

2. In the tooltip, I am not getting the string. It's only displaying the number.

[image]

```js
var options = {
  series: [{
    data: ["30 lac", "40 lac", "35 lac", "50 lac", "49 lac", "60 lac", "70 lac", "91 lac", "125 lac"]
  }],
  chart: {
    height: 350,
    type: 'bar',
    events: {
      click: function(chart, w, e) {
        // console.log(chart, w, e)
      }
    }
  },
  //colors: colors,
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      columnWidth: '45%',
      distributed: true,
    }
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  legend: {
    show: false
  },
  xaxis: {
    categories: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90],
    labels: {
      style: {
        // colors: colors,
        fontSize: '12px'
      }
    }
  },
  yaxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 200
  }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

```css
#chart {
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 35px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="chart"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
```

Answer (score 7):

1. You can change number of intervals with `tickAmount` https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/yaxis/#tickAmount
2. Use `tooltip` `formatter` https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/tooltip/#yformatter

```js
      var options = {
    series: [{
      data: ["30 lac", "40 lac", "35 lac", "50 lac", "49 lac", "60 lac", "70 lac", "91 lac", "125 lac"]
    }],
    chart: {
      height: 350,
      type: 'bar',
      events: {
        click: function (chart, w, e) {
          // console.log(chart, w, e)
        }
      }
    },
    //colors: colors,
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        columnWidth: '45%',
        distributed: true,
      }
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
      show: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      y: {
        formatter: function (value, {dataPointIndex, w}) {
          return w.config.series[0].data[dataPointIndex]
          //or you can judt add 'lac' to value
          //return `${value} lac`
        }
      }
    },
    xaxis: {
      categories: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90],
      labels: {
        style: {
          // colors: colors,
          fontSize: '12px'
        }
      }
    },
    yaxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 200,
      tickAmount: 4,
    }
  };

  var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
  chart.render();
```

```css
#chart {
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 35px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="chart"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, The second issue is working. In the first issue, why tickAmount: 4?

Comment: You can set any number, I used `tickAmount: 4` becouse it splits nicely when you heve 0-200 range, step by 50. If you use for example `tickAmount: 3` you will get [200, 133, 67, 0] which don't look that good.
PS: if your yaxis look wierd you can try adding `forceNiceScale:true`, might help

Comment: That is the point. I am not looking for good. I need to understand how it's working... As of now, I have 0-20, 20-40. means 20 value gap. Now how can I do 0-30, 30-60?

Comment: In apexcharts you can't set step size, only number of axis. You want step 30 so you take diffrence between min and max 200-0=200, we devide this by 30, 200/30=6.66666... (we want natural numbers) result is between 6 and 7 if we set those as our `tickAmount` axis won't be look too nice but if we change max to 210 and try again devide this by 30 210/30 = 7 and now when we set `tickAmount: 7` we get 30 step size

Comment: Thank you for the help. I think I have to use chart.js. It's good and easy to understand.